# #available iOSAppExtension vs. iOS

Tags: swift

I created a **Swift Package** that depends on another library. I'm running into a compiler error that happens inside the library I depend on:

```
if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 15.0, *) {
  tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance 
  // Error: 'scrollEdgeApperance is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer
}
```

Changing `iOSApplicationExtension` to `iOS` resolves the problem, but I'm curious - what's causing the error in the first place?

Comment: Is the problematic library for app targets or extension targets? How about your library? Without more context, it's impossible to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: The problematic library is used by app targets. My Swift Package will depend on this problematic library that will be used by app targets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#available` statement can not be used for detecting a target platform or a target type (app or extension) in compilation time and it can only describe a supported platform or target type and its version to run on. Thus `#available(iOSApplicationExtension 15.0, *)` means that your code works inside iOS extension ONLY and with a version that is equal or greater than 15.0. If you try to compile the statement on unsupported platform or target type the condition is ignored and compiler checks all code inside.

Other supported platforms and target types must be declared explicitly e.g.:

```swift
if #available(iOS 15.0, iOSApplicationExtension 15.0, *) {
    …
}
```

If your multi-platform code contains platform or target type depended API you should use compilation condition flags e.g.:

```swift
#if os(iOS)
    // iOS code only
#endif
    
#if IOS_EXTENSION
    // iOS extension code only
#endif
```

Where `IOS_EXTENSION` should be added to “Swift Compiler - Custom Flags” > “Active Compilation Conditions” for your extension target.

Comment: If you are re-using the widget on the watch, you might add:

`if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, watchOSApplicationExtension 10.0, watchOS 10, *) {   ...    }`